# How to call a JFrame and set look and feel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, look-and-feel

My program starts with a class that calls out a `JFrame`. On the frame, I have the LaF set up correctly, but when the main class calls it, the LaF doesn't take.

If I start only the file, it works. If I start the project, it doesn't.

The code below is under the main method on the frame.

```
try {
         UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaTur.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaTur.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaTur.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TelaTur.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

If the main class calls it:

```
TelaTur tela = new TelaTur();
    tela.setVisible(true);
```

It doesn't take. Opening just the file (on Netbeans Shift + F6) takes the LaF.

I´m looking for the answer to:

How to set the look and feel from the main class?

Comment: Try to run the setLookAndFeel before creating and showing the GUI.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  While it is **possible** to set the look and feel after GUI elements have been created, most uses of setting look and feel can be done a single time, before they are - so I suspect the best solution is as suggested @GilianJoosen ..

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on what @GilianJoosen wrote on comments.

I created a method named setLookAndFeel() and called it before the initComponents() method on the constructor.

Thanks for the answers.